# Android developing: Getting the name of Images

Tags: java, android, image, arraylist

Was searching for a bit here now but didnt find anything similar.
So my problem is:
I want to write a method that gets a filename and an ArrayList as a parameter with it and searchs through this Arraylist. When the filename equals the Name of the Image in this Arraylist, it should return this one.
Started to do it like this now:

```
private Image getEfnSig(String efn, ArrayList<Image> efnSignatures){
    for(int i=0; i<efnSignatures.size(); i++){
        if(efn.equals(efnSignatures.get(i).getClass().getName())){
            return efnSignatures.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My Problem here is, how do i get the name of an Image in this Arraylist. Because there are, like it seems, no Methods to just get the Name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File List to get image file path from name :

```
private String getImagePath(String name, ArrayList<File> files){
   for(int i=0; i<files.size(); i++){
       if(name.equals(files.get(i).getName())){
          return files.get(i).getAbsolutePath();
       }
   }
   return "";
}
```

Comment: Tried to make an ArrayList<File> now. But the problem is that i fill this list with Images before and then my eclipse tells me: "The method add(File) in the type ArrayList<File> is not applicable for the arguments (Image)"

Comment: Am I maybe doing still something wrong or is it not possible then?

Comment: Try to create File using image path like : File file = new File(imagePath).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html) documentation, there is no way to find out the file name of the image object. An image object should not always a file stored in file system.

You should pass to this method an ArrayList of File objects (like `ArrayList<File> files`) instead of Image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I solved my problem and it wasnt really realted to what I asked :D 
Was safing the Images before after giving a Signature in my App and just needed to get them in another order it was actually working. 
But thank you very much anyway Guys. 
Really love this Page and its Users for this great support here!

Comment: I dont know if I should actually post any code now here or something. Just tell me if yes and I'll be glad to do!